# SwiftUI State PropertyWrapper Behavior

Tags: swift, swiftui, rx-swift

I've formulated a previous question on a subject related to this, but more specifically now: I'm curious about the behavior of a `@State` variable when inside a closure, apparently from what I've tested the variable can't be updated, I've looked around a few articles but couldn't find the answer. Specifically, this is what I've been dealing with:

```
private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
@State var eventsView = [Event]()

func setObserver(){
    EventGroup.shared.events.asObservable()
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        [unowned self] events in
        print("Events Resp: "+String(events.count))
        self.eventsView = events
        print("Events Count: "+String(self.eventsView.count))
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

The result of the prints above is:

```
Events Resp: 3
Events Count: 0
```

How come, the `eventsView` variable is not updated?

Comment: `State` should only change within a function builder.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's docs:

> A State instance isn’t the value itself; it’s a means of reading and mutating the value. To access a state’s underlying value, use its value property.
>
> **Only access a state property from inside the view’s body (or from functions called by it)**. For this reason, you should declare your state properties as private, to prevent clients of your view from accessing it.